# JavaScript compare current value with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

I have a date picker, Kendo to be specific, the value is just a text string value.

I have an on change event firing and I want to compare the current value with the new selected value and then run it some extra code from there.  Pretty easy but form some reason I can't figure it out.

I can compare the initial value on document load but on change I need to know on every on change to compare the selected and the current value.

The values coming back in the console for the 'currentDateVal' on every change is the initial value on page load. But on change if someone is running through selecting dates over and over again the 'currentDateVal' is staying the same as the initial page load not the previously selected on a new selection each time.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentDateVal = $("#datepicker").val();
    console.log("initial date: " + currentDateVal);
    //Fill in initial Event Names
    $("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var selectedDateVal = $("#datepicker").val();
        //selectedDateVal = currentDateVal;
        console.log("on change current date val: " + currentDateVal);
        console.log("selected date val: " + selectedDateVal);
        if (currentDateVal !== selectedDateVal) {
            console.log("date changed");
        } else {
            console.log("date stayed the same");
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: Whats the actual issue? What is the output of those console logs?

Comment: People typically don't get downvoted for the level of skill required to answer a question, but instead they are downvoted for the lack of quality in the question itself.

Comment: @AlexDovzhanyn the values coming back for the 'currentDateVal' on every change is the initial value on page load.  But on change if someone is running through selecting dates over and over again the 'currentDateVal' is staying the same as the initial page load not the previously selected on a new selection each time.  I will try to get a JSFiddle or something up too.  But this should be pretty easy, very similar to a option list selection.

Comment: Edit the question with that detail. It is very relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never re-set `currentDateVal`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentDateVal = $("#datepicker").val();
    console.log("initial date: " + currentDateVal);
    //Fill in initial Event Names
    $("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var selectedDateVal = $("#datepicker").val();
        //selectedDateVal = currentDateVal;
        console.log("on change current date val: " + currentDateVal);
        console.log("selected date val: " + selectedDateVal);
        if (currentDateVal !== selectedDateVal) {
            console.log("date changed");
        } else {
            console.log("date stayed the same");
        }

        currentDateVal = selectedDateVal;
 });
```

Comment: There it is!  I had it backwards in my commented out code. I was on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you do it _after_ you need to perform any sort of comparison work. Obviously doing it beforehand will always result in equality.

Comment: It's a good example, but it wouldn't compare with initial date, which came from database or the same... As I understand `$("#datepicker").val()` return new value after every "change"